# The normal vector to the plane $5x+2y+3z=1$?

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

I am calculating the normal vector to the plane $5x+2y+3z=1$

According to the book:

The normal vector $N$ is often normalized to unit length because in that case
the equation
$$
    d = N ⋅Q + D 
$$
gives the signed distance from the plane to an arbitrary point $Q$. If $d = 0$, then the
point $Q$ lies in the plane. If $d > 0$, we say that the point $Q$ lies on the positive side of the plane since $Q$ would be on the side in which the normal vector points.

How to get thenormal vector $N$? Thank you

**Updated:
the normailize function**
$$
    q= \sqrt{q_0^2+q_1^2+q_2^2+q_3^2}
$$

Answer (score 3):

If $N$ is the unit normal to the plane, $p$ is a point in the plane and $q$ is any point then the signed distance $d$ of $q$ to the plane is
$$\langle(p-q), N\rangle = d$$
In coordinate representation this reads
$$\sum_i N_i (p_i-q_i) = d$$
The equation you have describes the set of $(x,y,z)$ which make up the plane. So simply by comparison, $n := (5,2,3)^T$ is a normal vector to your plane. It's not of unit length, though, so you need to normalize it if you want to have that.
That is, $$N = \frac{1}{\sqrt{38}}(5,2,3)^T$$
(because $5^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 = 38 $) and the distance of your plane to the origin is $\sqrt{38}$.

Comment: Thanks, i have checked the normalize function but how can it apply to my case? thanks

Comment: added this to the answer.